# Is it possible to receive a video stream from a user for a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to receive video from a user's screen sharing using a discord bot/api?

All I could find was that the discord developers are not going to add the ability for bots to stream themselves via go live.
And the fact that it is possible to get a preview of this from go live (https://gist.github.com/Hacksore/a0675b524fdcd1aabb3d8f97f7f5ae8d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Video Streams are not made available to Discord Bots. The linked post you mention refers to a private API Route, this is accessible to user accounts, however only provides the preview image and not the entire video stream and could be accomplished through [self-botting](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py-self/) however this is [disallowed as per Discord's statement](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).

For more information see this [discussion](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/3234) on the Discord API GitHub.